# "No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first." when DataGridView used with DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm getting this error message ("No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.") but I can't see anything wrong with my code. I swear I've done this hundreds of times but something is wrong.

```
class ViewItem {
   public string Name;
   public string Value;
}

...
BindingList<ViewItem> list=  new BindingList<ViewItem>();
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
ViewItem vi = new ViewItem(){Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar"};
list.Add(vi);
/// error here !
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The columns need to be declared as *Properties* and not just data members. Add `{get;set;}` to the class members that you want to appear as Columns in the data grid.

```
class ViewItem {
   public string Name { get;set;}
   public string Value { get;set;}
}

...
BindingList<ViewItem> list=  new BindingList<ViewItem>();
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
ViewItem vi = new ViewItem(){Name = "Foo", Value = "Bar"};
list.Add(vi);
/// works!
```